# Multiple result sets from MySQL stored-procedure in MS-Access front-end using vba?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, resultset, adodb

I'm familiar with using the ADODB Connection and ADODB Recordset in vba to iterate through records of a single result set from a stored-procedure from MySQL. But I now have a stored-procedure that returns multiple result sets. How do I access all result sets? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ADO [NextRecordset Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539%28VS.85%29.aspx)

See the [detailed example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677569%28VS.85%29.aspx) linked on that page.